# New laptop does not pick up WiFi signal when started up

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have a new win 8.1 laptop. The last few days the laptop does not pick up the WiFi signal when I switch it on, even though it is next to the router & my older Vista laptop does pick it up. However, when I switch the router off then on again, the new laptop does pick up the signal.
I have already set the wireless adaptor power settings to maximum & unchecked " Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option.
any suggestions?

Comment: Do you experience the same issue with anyother devices? for instance your mobile or desktop?

Comment: What make/model is the laptop (or its WiFi adaptor)?

Comment: Do you have many WiFi networks in your area? Try changing the WiFi channel and to see if the problem persists, it may be other networks interfering with yours.

Comment: @jjk: my old laptop does not have the issue, as stated in my original message, neither does my mobile Samsung S3.

Comment: @ Rowland: laptop is lenovo G510.

Comment: @ Caraxian: since my other devices are not affected it cannot be interference. Moreover, like I stated above, once I switch my router off then on again, my new laptop picks up the signal & holds it, so no interference.

Comment: If you are using 802.11n, try switch to 802.11g to see if things get better. Older hardware may implement 802.11n badly so that if is not compatible with new notebooks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by older hardware. The whole laptop is new so there for the adapter is too. What I experience is a sudden change. And the issue would not be fixed by switching the router off-on. The problem is only there when my laptop was switched off during the night & I switch it on in the morning, it does not connect, even though it "sees" the WiFi signal.